# So, here's a stats site for the challenge!

Tags: discussion, windows-8-challenge

Edit: As of 2015, I've stopped maintaining that domain and site. Someone else owns the domain now. If anyone is still interested in the data or wants to see the site back up, leave a comment and I'll see what I can do - but it's kinda pointless some 3 years after the actual challenge ended...

---

Born of boredom and an interesting idea in our own [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) chatroom is this site: <s>`http://win8challengestats.tk`</s>

It's a collection of statistics for the current Windows 8 Challenge. If there is anything you would like to see, please mention it!

It's not quite accurate to the contest, since there's no way to tell if votes were cast after the contest started. Therefore, it only counts questions and answers posted after the start date and before the end date.

Feel free to suggest anything!

A list of users who may be eligible for the competition, and a list of users who have been suspended/deleted (possibly for cheating), have been added.

Answer (score 5):

How about user specific stats?  Would it be possible for me to enter my user id and get these stats personalized?

Also, it'd be cool to see a leader board as well.  Who's on top (not so much level wise, but Q/A wise).  Similar to [something like this](https://superuser.com/tags/windows-8/topusers), but specific to the contest timing.

Comment: Yup, I'll do the user specific stats sometime today. I'll have to adapt the script to cache the data, since the API wouldn't be too happy if I start hammering it with requests :P

Comment: Go to http://win8challengestats.co.cc/cgi-bin/stats.py to filter by user